# Infinite loop after dividing in assembly NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to write a program in NASM assembly that convert a decimal number to binary.
So far I wrote some code that take the input number, divide it by 2 and display the remainder. But I have a problem, I get an infinite loop after division, in fact I'll always have in eax a number greater than 0.

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; nasm -felf decbin.asm && gcc decbin.o -o decbin
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
section .data
    in_message  db  "Enter a number in decimal:",0 ;input message
    out_message db  "The binary number is:%d",10,0 ;output message
    integer times 4 db  0                  ;32bits integer
    formatin    db  "%d",0
    binary      db  2;used for div
section .text
    global  main
    extern  printf
    extern  scanf
main:
;;; Ask for integer
    push    in_message
    call    printf
    add esp,4       ;remove parameters

    push    integer     ;address of integer where number will be stored
    push    formatin    ;%d parameter, arguments are right to left
    call    scanf
    add esp,8       ;remove parameters

    mov eax,[integer]
    jmp loop
    ;;; terminate if zero
    mov al,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
loop:
    xor edx,edx
    mov ebx,[binary]    ;mov binary to ebx
    div ebx
    push    edx
    push    formatin
    call    printf
    add esp,8
    cmp eax,0       ;compare the quotient with 0;
    jnz loop
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common calling convention is to place the return value from function calls into `eax` and, since `printf` returns the number of character printed, it will usually always be non-zero for a `"%d"` format string (unless you have an output failure of some type).

So, the call itself will probably be what's setting `eax` to a non-zero value.

To fix this, you need to save `eax` before calling `printf`, and then restore it afterwards, by changing:

```
push      edx
push      formatin
call      printf
add esp,  8
```

into:

```
push      eax        ; save here
push      edx
push      formatin
call      printf
add esp,  8
pop       eax        ; restore here
```

This will ensure that whatever `printf` does to `eax` will be irrelevant, since you're saving and restoring it yourself.